# BadImageFormatException when deploying on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, windows-server-2012-r2

I am deploying my Asp.net application on Windows Server 2012 R2(x64). I get a runtime BadImageFormatException while using 64-bit dll. When I run it with IIS Express or application published on local machine IIS everything works well (Application pools -> solution name -> Enable 32-bit applications set to False, All projects in solution are also set for Platform target x64). Deploy is going through Team City & Octopus Deploy.

What the solution could be?

**UPD**
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) at libxl.XmlBook.xlCreateXMLBookC() at xxx.Controllers.xxx.xxxController.LibxlTest() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\aeb63fe0b246a1f3\xxx\xxx\Controllers\xxx\xxx\xxxController.cs:line 597

There is no such path C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\ on server whrere the Octopus Tentacle is.

Comment: check the .NET Framework version. e.g. you might be trying to run assemblies built in .NET4.5 on a machine that only has .NET4.0

Comment: Thanks, but .NET Framework version is the same.

Comment: If you are using team city, make sure teamcity is configured to build the artefact for x64.

Comment: @DaiBak, unfortunately, didn't help.

Comment: are you sure you don't have a 32-bit dll in any of your references? you can inspect with a tool like http://ilspy.net/ or http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: @user326608.  
"This file does not contain a managed assembly." with both tools.

Comment: OK, well, that doesn't look good. How is it that the dll is running on your local machine then? It must be that the deployed dll is being mangled somehow. It sounds like a problem in your CI/CD system

Comment: @user326608, I've added some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it works with x86 (from `bin` folder) version while the solution was build for x64. Probably, it is a peculiarity of `libxl`. Thus, I'm developing with x64 and after deploy my post-deploy script changes it for x86 version.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like you or one of your references has a dependency on [libXL](http://www.libxl.com).

Your exception result ([0x8007000B](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx)) is definitely a 32-bit can't load on 64-bit issue.

libXL is C++ project, in the [download zip](http://www.libxl.com/download.html) there's a `bin64` folder with a copy of `libxl.dll` that will work in 64-bit mode.

If you have a libXL licensed copy better to use the 64-bit dll from that.

Note that `C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\` comes from the machine your project was built on, the line numbers etc get saved into your `pdb` files.

Comment: I've got about pdb files, thanks. Server is definitely x64 and I use libxl.dll exactly from bin64 folder (~9mb)